# How to use ffmpeg ffpreset files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

My ffmpeg comes with some ffpreset files:

```
$ ls /usr/share/ffmpeg
libvpx-1080p.ffpreset       libvpx-360p.ffpreset  libvpx-720p50_60.ffpreset
libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset  libvpx-720p.ffpreset
```

I'm wondering how can I use them, i.e., specifying different preset files from the command line, and if I can customize them at all?

In https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg, it says,

For "using preset files, enable the `-vpre` option after declaring the desired `-vcodec`". I don't quite understand what it is saying, and what exactly to do.

But somewhere above it, at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg#x265, using the preset is like this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -aspect 1920:1080 -preset veryslow -x265-params crf 20 output
```

Where can I find the meaning of this `veryslow`, and other similar options as such?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of reading the Arch Wiki, rather check the [ffmpeg documentation on the preset options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Preset-files). All should be explained there.

Note that there are three different kinds of presets:

- **`.ffpreset` files:**  You define `option=value` pairs in those files and for video settings you generally use them with `-vpre`. Depending on the encoder you select, ffmpeg will then search for a matching `ffpreset` file. For example, if you set `-vcodec libvpx` (or `-c:v libvpx`), and `-vpre 1080p`, then ffmpeg will load the `libvpx-1080p.ffpreset` file.

  You can also, more generally, use `-pre` and specify `vcodec=libvpx` as an option/value pair in the `.ffpreset` file. This allows you to set video and audio encoders at the same time. For example, you simply call `-pre custom`, and ffmpeg will load the `custom.ffpreset` file.
- **`.avpreset` files:** work similar to `-vpre` or `-apre` presets — those are mostly for compatibility with Libav.
- **x264 presets:** x264 is an H.264 encoder (used in ffmpeg with `-c:v libx264`). It has several presets which basically control the speed of the encoder in inverse relation to the quality or efficiency of the encoding process. Those presets have nothing to do with ffmpeg's presets, and they're called with the `-preset` option. They have names like `ultrafast`, `superfast`, `veryfast`, `faster`, `fast`, `medium`, `slow`, `slower` or `veryslow`. Read the [H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more about that, or call `x264 --fullhelp` for the preset description.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a very related question? Suppose I've set my values in my own custom `.ffpreset` file, and use `-vpre` to pull them in, can I then override some from the command line? Say to use `qmax` and `qmin` from the command line to override that define in `.ffpreset` file? If yes, should I define them before using `-vpre` or after? I remember that `ffmpeg` has a unique feature that for the same option, if defined twice or more on the command line, then the former value take priority over the latter, whereas most programs are other way around. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I don't know by heart – just give it a try. I suppose that options from the commandline override preset options, indepentent of where they are specified. But I'm really not sure.